# How to use CJK ruby for diacritics only

Tags: cjk

Ruby for CJK is designed to put whole words above characters.  But I want just the diacritics and not the pinyin spelling.  This file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage[overlap, CJK]{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysize}{1}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}\ruby{自}{\'{}}\ruby{柏}{\'{}}\ruby{拉}{\={}}\ruby{图}{\'{}}\ruby{以}{\u{}}\ruby{来}{\'{}} \end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

gives pretty good output as shown below.

But I would like to get rid of the blank vertical space that was left for the pinyin letters that I do not want shown.

Is there a way to lower the tone marks?

[image: output of code]

Comment: Off-topic, but "自" should be ``\`{}`` instead of `\'{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the size of `\rubysep` (which oddly is a macro and not a length):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage[overlap, CJK]{ruby}
\renewcommand{\rubysize}{1}
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{-1.5ex}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}\ruby{自}{\'{}}\ruby{柏}{\'{}}\ruby{拉}{\={}}\ruby{图}{\'{}}\ruby{以}{\u{}}\ruby{来}{\'{}} \end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]