# New command buttons similar to \"o in WinEdt

Tags: winedt

I am not a serious programmer and this may just be over my head.  But I would like to be able to create a few new buttons that would work the way buttons like \"o work in the WinEdt GUI Page Control bar do.

That is, you can select a letter, say "`a`", in your file, then click on the button  `\"o` in the WinEdt GUI Page Control bar, and WinEdt will insert `\"{a}` in your file.

I have designed a few new commands sort of like `\"{}` (with help from Alan Munn [How to use CJK ruby for diacritics only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372227/how-to-use-cjk-ruby-for-diacritics-only/372233#372233)).  And it would save me a lot of work if I could just select a character in the file and click a button and get one of these commands wrapped around that character.

Is there an easy way to do that?

As far as I can see the questions [Quick Build commands in WinEdt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119101/quick-build-commands-in-winedt) and [Adding a new command in Winedt 8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178719/adding-a-new-command-in-winedt-8?noredirect=1&lq=1) do not address my goal of getting the command wrapped around a piece of text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course it is possible. Follow these steps.

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]
2. Double-click the "Main Menu" item (`MainMenu.ini` gets opened)
3. Just before the line

   ```
   END="User_Menu"
   ```

   add the following lines

   ```
     ITEM="\""{}"  // use the name you want, but remember that this will be the name of your button
       CAPTION="\""{}"
       IMAGE="Delim"  // double-click on IMAGE and choose the image you want
       MACRO="IfSel(2,'>','SetSel(0);');IfSel(0,'=',|Ins('\""{}');"+
             "CharLeft;|,|InsLabel('','\""{','}');|);"
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd>
5. Now (in the "Options Interface") double-click the "Toolbar" item (`Toolbar.ini` gets opened)
6. Put the line

   ```
     BUTTON="\""{}"
   ```

   wherever you want in the file in the point where you want the button.
7. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd>

---

That's it. Now you have a toolbar button

[image]

that inserts what you wanted.

---

Notice that the character `"` is used by WinEdt as a string delimiter, so to obtain `"` you have to double it (`""`). The same might be needed for the character `'` if you want to insert something with it.

For example, if you want a macro to insert `\'{}`, you'll have to use

```
    MACRO="IfSel(2,'>','SetSel(0);');IfSel(0,'=',|Ins('\''{}');"+
          "CharLeft;|,|InsLabel('','\''{','}');|);"
```

Comment: Grazie @Sebastiano

Comment: You're great, I'm a lot worse. See also my score. I only answer easy questions.

Comment: When you say "use the name you want," I believe the name goes this way:  ITEM="\NAME_HERE""{}" but I am not sure.  Is that right?  Does the name also go after the backslash in CAPTION="\""{}"?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty `ITEM` is a symbolic name which serves as a refer for `BUTTON` in Toolbar.ini, while `CAPTION` is the name which will be displayed when the mouse hover over the button. `CAPTION` is also the name of the menu item as displayed in the menu (when visible). Try to change the property `INVISIBLE` from `1` to `0` for `MENU="User_Menu"` to see your commands in the main menu, also.